# How to implement multithreading on DBSCAN clustering algorithm?

Tags: java, multithreading, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have implemented dbscan algorithm to cluster 3d point cloud data. It works very well indeed but the only problem is that it takes too long processing time. almost 15secs for 6000 point cloud. Wanna implement multithreading to reduce the processing time. Would highly appreciate it if one could help with implementing multithreading on the following complete piece of code. Thanks!

```
public ArrayList<List<Vector>> Run() {
    int index = 0;                      //index for each point cloud (cloud -->input data)
    List <Vector> neighbors;
    ArrayList<List<Vector>> resultList = new ArrayList<List<Vector>>();     //group of cluster --> ArrayList<list<Vector>>
    while (cloud.size() > index) {
        Vector p = cloud.get(index);
        if (!visited.contains(p)) {
            visited.add(p);
            neighbors = get_neighbors(p);
            if (neighbors.size() >= minPts) {                               //minpts = 5
                int ind = 0;
                while (neighbors.size() > ind) {
                    Vector r = neighbors.get(ind);
                    if (!visited.contains(r)) {
                        visited.add(r);
                        List<Vector> individualNeighbors = get_neighbors(r);
                        if (individualNeighbors.size() >= minPts) {
                            neighbors = merge_neighbors(
                                    neighbors,
                                    individualNeighbors);
                        }
                    }
                    ind++;
                }
                resultList.add(neighbors);
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
    return resultList;
}

private List<Vector> merge_neighbors(List<Vector>neighborPts1, List<Vector>neighborPts2) {
    for (Vector n2: neighborPts2) {
        if (!neighborPts1.contains(n2)) {
            neighborPts1.add(n2);
        }
    }
    return neighborPts1;
}

private List<Vector> get_neighbors(Vector pt){
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Vector> pts = new  CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    for (Vector p: cloud) {
            if (computeDistance (pt,p)<=eps*eps) {
                pts.add(p);
        }
    }
    return pts;
}
private double computeDistance (Vector core,Vector target) {
    return Math.pow(core.getX()-target.getX(),2)
            + Math.pow(core.getY()-target.getY(),2)
            +Math.pow(core.getZ()-target.getZ(),2);
}       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A) there is lot of optimization potential in your implementation that is easier to do than multithreading. So first optimize your code.

In particular, if you load your data into tools such as ELKI (make sure to add a spatial index, which is not default), you'll notice that they run much faster even with just a single thread

B) there are publications on multicore DBSCAN that discuss the difficulties and challenges when pallelizing DBSCAN. Read then first, as the whole story is to long for this Q&A format here:

> Patwary, M. A., Palsetia, D., Agrawal, A., Liao, W. K., Manne, F., & Choudhary, A. (2012, November). A new scalable parallel DBSCAN algorithm using the disjoint-set data structure. In Proceedings of the International Conference on High Performance Computing, Networking, Storage and Analysis (p. 62). IEEE Computer Society Press.
>
> Götz, M., Bodenstein, C., & Riedel, M. (2015, November). HPDBSCAN: highly parallel DBSCAN. In Proceedings of the workshop on machine learning in high-performance computing environments (p. 2). ACM.
>
> Welton, B., Samanas, E., & Miller, B. P. (2013, November). Mr. scan: Extreme scale density-based clustering using a tree-based network of gpgpu nodes. In SC'13: Proceedings of the International Conference on High Performance Computing, Networking, Storage and Analysis (pp. 1-11). IEEE.

Comment: Appreciate your answer! Through my own research, I found out that implementing k-d tree algorithm also improves its performance significantly and will reduce its complexity from O(n^2) to O(n log n). That seems amazing, isn't it?  Also, I couldn't understand why some people without mentioning anything downvoting the question.